# How to create a down arrow using CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I try to do an arrow with transparent color inside and coloured border but I'm new in this world .
Someone can help me to do something like this:
[arrow down with text inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUPFs.png)

My code:

```
.pentagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    top:20rem;
    left: 20rem;
    border-width: 80px 0 100px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #01ff70 transparent;
}
.pentagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: -7.5rem;
    border-width: 100px 300px 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #01ff70;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Search and learn from tutorials how things work. Here is one example https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: ok ok sorry, i had already do some code but i don't think was necessary to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build this with multiple gradient to create each line:

```css
.arrow {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:

    linear-gradient(blue,blue)  top center/ 100px 3px,
    
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)  calc(50% - 50px) 0/3px 50%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)  calc(50% + 50px) 0/3px 50%,
    
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)  0 50%/51px 3px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)  100% 50%/51px 3px,
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - 2px),blue calc(50% - 2px),
      calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 2px)) 100% 100%/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,
      transparent calc(50% - 2px),blue calc(50% - 2px),
      calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 2px)) 0 100%/50% 50%;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  text inside
</div>
```

And with some CSS variable to control the different values:

```css
.arrow {
  --c:blue; /*main color*/
  --t:2px; /*thickness*/
  --d: 100px; /*top length*/
  --p:50%; /*percentage of top*/
  
  --g:linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c));
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*1*/
    var(--g) top center/ var(--d) var(--t),
    /*2*/
    var(--g)  calc(50% - var(--d)/2) 0/var(--t) calc(var(--p) + var(--t)/2),
    var(--g)  calc(50% + var(--d)/2) 0/var(--t) calc(var(--p) + var(--t)/2),
    /*3*/
    var(--g)  left  0 top var(--p)/calc(50% - var(--d)/2) var(--t),
    var(--g)  right 0 top var(--p)/calc(50% - var(--d)/2) var(--t),
    /*4*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - var(--t)/2 - 1px),var(--c) calc(50% - var(--t)/2),
      calc(50% + var(--t)/2),transparent calc(50% + var(--t)/2 + 0.5px)) 100% 100%/50% calc(100% - var(--p)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,
      transparent calc(50% - var(--t)/2 - 1px),var(--c) calc(50% - var(--t)/2),
      calc(50% + var(--t)/2),transparent calc(50% + var(--t)/2 + 0.5px)) 0 100%/50% calc(100% - var(--p));
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;  
  text-align:center;
  line-height:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  text inside 
</div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:red;--t:5px;--d:40px;--p:40%">
 text inside
</div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:green;--t:3px;--d:70px;--p:60%">
 text inside
</div>
```

1. a line placed at the `top center` with a width equal to `--d` and a height equal to `--t`
2. The two vertical lines with a width equal to `--t` and a height equal `--p` + half the thickness to have them correctly linked with the bottom part. We place the first line at the top `0` and from the center we remove half `--d` so it start at the left of the top line. Same logic with the other line at the right.
3. The two horizontal lines with a width equal to half the width left by the top line `(100% - var(--d))/2` and a height equal to `--t`. Their placement is easy to find. the left one at `0` from the left and `--p` from the top. Same logic for the right one.
4. The two diagonal lines are two gradient that will take half the width and `100% - var(--p)`. Here we play with the coloration to color only a diganonal part and we keep the remaining transparent.

---

If you want more, we can add a coloration inside the arrow:

```css
.arrow {
  --c:blue; /*main color*/
  --b:red; /*background color*/
  --t:2px; /*thickness*/
  --d: 100px; /*top length*/
  --p:50%; /*percentage of top*/
  
  --g:linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c));
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*1*/
    var(--g) top center/ var(--d) var(--t),
    /*2*/
    var(--g)  calc(50% - var(--d)/2) 0/var(--t) calc(var(--p) + var(--t)/2),
    var(--g)  calc(50% + var(--d)/2) 0/var(--t) calc(var(--p) + var(--t)/2),
    /*3*/
    var(--g)  left  0 top var(--p)/calc(50% - var(--d)/2) var(--t),
    var(--g)  right 0 top var(--p)/calc(50% - var(--d)/2) var(--t),
    /*4*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      var(--b) calc(50% - var(--t)/2 - 1px),var(--c) calc(50% - var(--t)/2),
      calc(50% + var(--t)/2),transparent calc(50% + var(--t)/2 + 0.5px)) 100% 100%/50% calc(100% - var(--p)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,
      var(--b) calc(50% - var(--t)/2 - 1px),var(--c) calc(50% - var(--t)/2),
      calc(50% + var(--t)/2),transparent calc(50% + var(--t)/2 + 0.5px)) 0 100%/50% calc(100% - var(--p)),
     /*5*/
     linear-gradient(var(--b),var(--b)) center top/var(--d) var(--p);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;  
  text-align:center;
  line-height:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  text inside
</div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:red;--b:yellow;--t:5px;--d:40px;--p:40%">
  text inside
</div>
<div class="arrow" style="--c:green;--b:pink;--t:3px;--d:70px;--p:60%">
  text inside
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `clip-path` on a div.

```
.arrow { 
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 60% 20%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 60% 80%, 0% 80%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 60% 20%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 60% 80%, 0% 80%);
}
```

There is a convinient tool for this on https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Just want to mention, that this does not work in IE, Edge and Safari

Comment: I had already seen this site but I don't like to much this way

Comment: I would strongly advice against that!! this was de best i could do in a short time. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzZXya

Comment: It is true that clip-path has poor support. It is not bad practice to have different designs on different browsers. There are specific media queries for that anyway.

Comment: It's identical to my code but i can not make the arrow trasparent inside with border coloured